# How could I calculate $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{x(t)}{t^{\sqrt{3}}}$ for the following

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, bessel-functions

If $x(t)$ satisfy $t^2x''+tx'+(t^2-3)x=0$ then what is the limit $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{x(t)}{t^{\sqrt{3}}}$$

It is very important to me, hint or full help, please. I know that the solution to the differential equation is a Bessel function so its solution are determinate by $$\{ J_\sqrt{3}(t)\ ;\ J_{-\sqrt{3}}(t)\}\ \ \ \ (because \ \alpha\not\in\mathbb{Z})$$
but I have big problem when I work with $J$ bessel. I need help please.

Comment: Better to improve the title, so that you get more attention.

Comment: If your ODE is indeed $\cdots(t^2 - 3^2) = 0$, then the two independent solutions are $J_3(x)$ and $Y_3(x)$, not $J_{\pm\sqrt{3}}(x)$. Only the $J_3(x)$ is regular at $x = 0$.

Comment: @Winther yes I correct thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10), you can find a lot of information on the behaviour of Bessel functions. For example, using [equation (10.2.2)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2#E2) therein, you see that $\frac{J_{\sqrt{3}}(t)}{t^{\sqrt{3}}}$ converges as $t \downarrow 0$. For the Bessel function of the second kind, $Y_{\sqrt{3}}(t)$, you can use [equation (10.2.3)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2#E3) in combination with equation (10.2.2) to figure out if $\frac{Y_{\sqrt{3}}(t)}{t^{\sqrt{3}}}$ converges as $t \downarrow 0$.